# groupby and select mode and join back onto original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, mode

I have data that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['John', 'John', 'John', 'Darrel','Darrel', 'Nick'], 
                  'Ocupation' : ['An','An', 'An', 'Se', 'So', 'Ik'],
                  'Numbers' : ['12','12','54','2', '3', '55']})
```

I want to group by `Name` and for each group in `Name` I want to select the mode (most frequent/prevalent value) of `Numbers`. I do this with the following code:

```
df.groupby(['Name'])['Numbers'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]).reset_index(False)
```

, and now I want to join back the modes onto `df`. Is there any way to do this in one go?

Right now I have to do the maybe not so elegant:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['Name'])['Numbers'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]).reset_index(False),
       left_on='Name', right_on='Name', how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want mode you can use:

```
from statistics import mode
df['Mode'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Numbers'].transform(mode)
```

Comment: beautiful, I did not know of the `transform`, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby().transform()` instead of `groupby().agg()`:

```
df['Mode'] = df.groupby('Name')['Numbers'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
     Name Ocupation Numbers Mode
0    John        An      12   12
1    John        An      12   12
2    John        An      54   12
3  Darrel        Se       2    2
4  Darrel        So       3    2
5    Nick        Ik      55   55
```

Comment: beautiful, I did not know of the `transform`, thank you very much!